# Proving the triangle inequality for the $l_2$ norm $\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots+x_n^2}$

Tags: solution-verification, normed-spaces, vector-analysis

I want to prove the triangle inequality for the $l_2$-norm $\|x\|_2$:
$$\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots+x_n^2}$$

---

\begin{align}
  \sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i + y_i)^2 }  &\leqslant \sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}  + \sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2} \\ 
  \sum_{i=1}^n {(x_i + y_i)}^2  &\leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2  + 2\sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2 }  + \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2 \\ 
  \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i^2 + 2x_i y_i + y_i^2)  &\leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + 2\sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 } \sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2 }  + \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2 \\ 
  \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2 + 2\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i  &\leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2 + 2\sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 } \sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^n {y_i^2} }  \\ 
  \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i  &\leqslant \sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 } \sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2 }  \end{align}
After this I squared both sides and multiplied out. It gets really messy, and then I got stuck. I think you have to realize some factorization and then conclude $0\leq$ some terms.

How do I finish this proof?  All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Someone, please edit that mess...

Comment: I found no other way out but to use summation notation to make things compact.

Comment: Writing {{\left( {{{x_i}^2 + {y_i}^2}} \right)}} where (x_i^2 + y_i^2) suffices and produces exactly the same final result doesn't make the code easier to understand or edit. And I don't understand the point of including a line that consists of well over a hundred blank spaces. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Also, $\|a\|\|b\|$ looks different from $||a||||b||$.  The former is standard usage. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to prove that $$\lVert x+y\rVert \leq \lVert x\rVert+\lVert y\rVert$$

We use $\langle x,y\rangle$ to denote the inner (dot) product $$x\cdot y=\sum_{k=1}^n x_ky_k$$
Note that $$\lVert x+y\rVert ^2=\lVert x\rVert^2+2\langle x,y\rangle+\lVert y\rVert ^2$$

Continuing, use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, you get  $$\lVert x\rVert^2+2\langle x,y\rangle+\lVert y\rVert ^2\leq \lVert x\rVert^2+2 \lVert x\rVert \cdot \lVert y\rVert +\lVert y\rVert ^2=\left(\lVert x\rVert+\lVert y\rVert\right)^2 $$ and since all is positive, we can obtain your inequality by taking square roots.
The last equation you got is *almost* $$|\langle x,y\rangle|\leq \lVert x\rVert \cdot \lVert y\rVert $$

which is known as the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is true for any [inner product space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space), and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Proof) you have the canonical proof. Your inequality is a particular case of the [Minkowski inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality) for $L_p$ norms.

**ADD** To clear out the proof in Wikiepdia

Recall that the nature of roots of the polynomial $aX^2+bX+c$ are intimately related to its discriminant: $\Delta=b^2-4ac$ which appears in the formula $$X=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$$

If a quadratic polynomial is proven to satisfy $p(X)\geq 0$ then $\Delta \leq 0$: either there is one real root $\Delta=0$ or there are no real roots ($\Delta<0$) because the square root of the negative discriminant will give rise to complex numbers.

Comment: How would I proceed after multiplying out?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus You use the CS inequality. Let me add something.

Comment: I don't understand your first line: $||x+y||^2 = ||x||^2 +2\langle x,y\rangle + ||y||^2$ What is the $2\langle x, y\rangle$? It looks like a vector to me. How do you add vectors and reals?

Comment: Could you explain to me the proof in wikipedia that mentions the polynomial in $z$? I am confused with the sentence: "Since it is nonnegative it has at most one real root in z, whence its discriminant is less than or equal to zero, that is" Here is the link to the exact spot: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Notable_special_cases

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus Is it clear now?

Comment: Thanks so much! This is probably one of the most helpful answers I have ever gotten!

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus I'm glad. You're welcome. I do recommend, when you read about the general notion of inner products, that you re-read the article and see the proof in more generality.

Answer (score -2):

I did exactly what you did above. That was actually a very good proof--better than using $u$ and $v$ since it is more abstract, hence more generalized than the latter one. You should proceed with your work, for you are almost there.

To continue with what you wrote above, you should notice that the left side of the very last equation you got is the inner product of vector $x$ and vector $y$: ${}=x^\text Ty=\|x\|\,\|y\|\cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $x$ and $y$. Now $\cos(\theta)$ is always less than or equal to 1. Hence you have the inequality. Hope this helps.